# Can I ask about openLDAP and an LDIF script here?

Tags: support

I have a seemingly simple problem with adding two attributes to an objectClass in a running/live ldap instance.

Expecting it to be off-topic for SO, can I ask this question on SF or would Unix and/or SU be more appropiate?

If it can go on SF, do I need to add any extra information beyond the script and the error-message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the question it's difficult to tell really so the best thing to do is just ask it and see what the community thinks. The worst that will happen is you collect a few downvotes and it gets closed.

Comment: Agreed, sounds like it would be on-topic, but hard to tell sometimes...